# Run API test in CI (Jenkins)

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

What is the best way to run an API test that was created via the IBM API Connect Test and Monitor ? 
I published a test and I would like my CI sever (jenkins or azure devops) to run it?

Many thanks,

Assaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question Assaf. It is currently not possible in the product, however, is on the roadmap and is coming soon.

We will have APIs and Webhooks to help execute tests as part of your CI/CD processes. Meaning, the same tests you generated using the test composer and run in production can be recycled to ensure your deployments are error free.

As well, Jenkins is an industry standard so we will be providing a plugin to help facilitate the API testing processes via GUI. More details to come, will update this space when it does.

Alternatively keep your eye out here: http://ibm.biz/apitest